# Create a reusable React Native Modal Component

Tags: react-native

I'm going back to basics with React Native, as I feel overwhelmed. I have been looking for an implementation of a reusable modal component. I'm looking for examples of a reusable Modal component in RN? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can find many examples of this on StackOverflow. Still, if you need example I can help you with one example. You have mentioned modal component in your question, right?

Your component will look like this with props. let the name be ModalComponent for this file.

```
render() {
    const { isVisible, message, textValue } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        isVisible={isVisible}
        backdropColor={"white"}
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        onModalHide={() => {}}>
        <View>
          <Text>textValue</Text>
          <Text>message</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
```

so now in your js file you need to import this modalComponent and after that, you need to write as

```
  <ModalComponent 
       isVisible={true}
       textValue={'hi there'}
       message={'trying to make a basic component modal'}/>
```

Hope this will help for you

EDIT:

Create seperate components that you want to render inside modal. for Ex: component1.js, component2.js, component3.js with props

component1.js:

```
render(){
    const { textVal, message } = this.props
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{textVal}</Text>
        <Text>{message}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

now in ModalComponent

```
render() {
  const { first, second, third, isVisible, component1Text, component1Message } = this.props;



  <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      isVisible={isVisible}
      backdropColor={"white"}
      style={{ margin: 0 }}
      onModalHide={() => {}}>
      <View>
        {first && <component1
          textValue= component1Text
          message= component1Message />}
        {second && <Component2 />}
        {third && <Component2 />}
      </View>
    </Modal>
```

In this way, you can achieve it within the single modal.

Comment: Thank you. The main reason I ask the question is that in an app that I would like to create I would be using modals many times. The only issue is that the content in the modal component would change so in one place where it would be called a form will be displayed, and another place  just some text would be displayed, so the component you suggest wouldn't work how could implement this? Thanks

Comment: Even that one is possible. All you need to do is make use of your props correctly with seperate components. I will edit my answer. I think that will give you idea.

Answer (score 1):

You will make a component like this giving the parent component all the liberty to change it through props.

```
render() {
  const { isVisible, message, textValue, animationType, backDropColor, style, onModalHide, children } = this.props;
  return (
    <Modal
      animationType= {animationType || 'slide'}
      transparent={transparent || false}
      isVisible={isVisible || false}
      backdropColor={backdropColor || "white"}
      style={[modalStyle, style]}
      onModalHide={onModalHide}>
      {children}
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Then in your parent component, you need to import this component like this:

```
import ModalComponent from '../ModalComponent'; //path to your component

<ModalComponent isVisible={true}>
  <View>
    //any view you want to be rendered in the modal
  </View>
</ModalComponent>
```

Comment: You have a typo on childern

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of troubles using react-native modal, sometimes i started the app and could not close it even when i set the isVisible prop to false, it is even worst on IOs, i did a research and these packages are not being maintained properly.

You will save a lot of time by using a top-level navigator like is recommended in the modal docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.

I tried https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal but had the same problems because its an extension of the original react-native modal.

I suggest you to use the react-navigation modal as described here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/modal.html#docsNav

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following code to write Modal component once and use multiple times.

Write once:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, Text, Button, Modal, ScrollView, } from 'react-native';

export class MyOwnModal extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

}

      render() {

         return(

            <Modal
            key={this.props.modalKey}
            transparent={this.props.istransparent !== undefined ? true : false}
            visible={this.props.visible}
            onRequestClose={this.props.onRequestClose}>

            <View style={{
                //your styles for modal here. Example:
                marginHorizontal: width(10), marginVertical: '30%',
                height: '40%', borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.38)', padding: 5,
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#fff', elevation: 5, shadowRadius: 20, shadowOffset: { width: 3, height: 3 }
            }}>

                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </ScrollView>

            </View>
        </Modal>
        );
     }
   }
```

Now,

You can call your Modal like following example: (By doing this, you avoid re-writing the Modal and its outer styles everytime!)

Example

```
  <MyOwnModal modalKey={"01"} visible={true} onRequestClose={() => 
     this.anyFunction()} istransparent = {true}>

    <View>
       // create your own view here!
    </View>

  </MyOwnModal>
```

Note: If you are in using different files don't forget to import , and also you can pass the styles as props.

(You can create/customise props too based on your requirement)

Hope this saves your time.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I am a contributor of [react-native-use-modal](https://github.com/zeallat/react-native-use-modal).

This is an example of creating a reusable modal in a general way and using `react-native-use-modal`: https://github.com/zeallat/creating-reusable-react-native-alert-modal-examples

With `react-native-use-modal`, you can make reusable modal more easily.

This is a comparison article with the general method: https://zeallat94.medium.com/creating-a-reusable-reactnative-alert-modal-db5cbe7e5c2b